# AWS S3 TransferUtility.UploadDirectoryRequest and HTTP PUT Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipart, awss3transferutility

Here is a little background. I have designed a WEB API which provides methods for cloud operations(upload, download..). This API internally calls AWS API methods to fulfill these cloud operation requests.

WebDev solution --> WEB API --> AWS API

I am trying to upload a directory to AWS S3 cloud. This directory has large individual files more than 5 GB each. Amazon S3 has a limit of 5 GB for a single PUT operation. But They have provided a multi part upload mechanism using which files upto 5 TB can be uploaded.

The AWS documentation said the TransferUtility.UploadDirectory method will use multi-part upload mechanism to upload large files. So In my WEB API a [PUT] UploadDirectoryMethod method calls TransferUtility.UploadDirectory to upload the directory. 
I am receiving an error "Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size"

1. Shouldn't the TransferUtility.UploadDirectory take care of breaking the larger objects (larger then 5GB) into parts and they uploading them with multiple PUT(?) operations?
2. How does Multi-part upload work internally for objects more then 5 GB in size? Does it create multiple PUT requests internally?

Comment: I have not used TransferUtility but the multipart upload process and API are well-[documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html).  I wrote my own library to use the REST API directly.  It's pretty straightforward, if you're so inclined.

Comment: @Michael Yes, they do have good documentation and I have gone through it thoroughly. The documentation only says TransferUtility will use multi part API to break large objects into smaller chunks". I want to know if it does it only up to 5 GB(because it is one single PUT request) or it does it for all objects in the directory regardless if they are more then 5 GB with multi part API internally? How does multi part API work in the background does it use multiple PUT's?